# KQL for SQL Databases based on Reliability WB

Tags: sql-server, azure, kql

Is there a way for me to display the SKU name (ex: generalpurpose) for my SQL databases using Kustos? I'm just trying to generate what I see in the Reliability workbook in Azure.

Here is my query for now

```
// Azure Resource Graph Query
// Find all SQLs that are not assigned to a Zone
Resources
| where type == "microsoft.sql/servers"
| where isnull(zones)
| where location == 'australiaeast'
| join kind=leftouter  ( 
    resourcecontainers
        | where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions"
        | extend resolvedSubId = tostring(split(id, '/', 2)[0]), subscriptionName = name
        | project resolvedSubId, subscriptionName
) on $left.subscriptionId == $right.resolvedSubId
| project recommendationId = "DB", DatabaseName=name, subscriptionId, subscriptionName, location, AvaiabilityZone="Zones: No Zone", resourceGroup, kind
```

I'm trying to include "sku" but its returning null. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

`SKU` is property of SQL database and not of SQL Server. That is the reason, you get null values in your query result. Also, the name in your query is `servername` and it is not `databaseName`. You can include the SKU name for your SQL databases in your Kusto query by joining the `microsoft.sql/servers/databases` resources to your existing query. Below is the query,

```
Resources
| where type == "microsoft.sql/servers"
| where isnull(zones)
| where location == 'australiaeast'
| join kind=leftouter  ( 
    resourcecontainers
        | where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions"
        | extend resolvedSubId = tostring(split(id, '/', 2)[0]), subscriptionName = name
        | project resolvedSubId, subscriptionName
) on $left.subscriptionId == $right.resolvedSubId
| join kind=leftouter (
    resources
    | where type == "microsoft.sql/servers/databases"
    | project DatabaseName = name, serverName = tostring(split(id, '/')[8]),sku
) on $left.name == $right.serverName
| project recommendationId = "DB", DatabaseName, subscriptionId, subscriptionName, location, AvaiabilityZone="Zones: No Zone", resourceGroup, kind, sku
```

This query joins the `microsoft.sql/servers/databases` resource type to your existing query using the `serverName` property. Split function is used to extract the `server name` from `resourceid`. It splits the resource id into an array based on `\`. Index 8 in that array gives the `server name`. It then projects the `databasename` and `sku` properties of the databases and joins the resulting table to your existing query using the `name` and `serverName` properties. Finally, it projects the required columns.

Comment: When I tried it, it still says null for SKU

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of ur code and output

Comment: It's the one given by Dale above. The output is as expected. all columns has been populated except SKU says its null. Not able to post some screenshot for privacy reasons.

Comment: I used where type == "microsoft.sql/servers/databases" instead of "microsoft.sql/servers" so i think this works.